# What is the meaning of Illuminate in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Every time I am writing code in different classes of Laravel where I saw the keyword **`Illuminate`** always. I cannot understand what is the meaning of it. Please explain it to me?

Comment: In simple words it is just a name given to all the package services provided by laravel, see [laravel framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework) , src has directory called illuminate which contains everything laravel as a framework provides to you

Answer (score 67):

`Illuminate` is the namespace Laravel choose to put their code in. The word Illuminate means to light-up something. By using Laravel you are illuminating PHP development experience in their terms, hence the name.

That's it; just a namespace.

Comment: Thanks for illuminating us with this meaning. 